# How to conditionally render different screens in Stack Navigator depending on props

Tags: react-native, navigation, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering, stack-navigator

Is it possible to render a different screen in the StackNavigator depending on props, params or state?

I was thinking something like the below but at the moment I can't seem to work out how to allow stackNavigator to have scope over the screen's params.

```
export const MainNavigation = StackNavigator({
  Interests: {
    screen: navigation.state.params.interests ? InterestsScreen : ChooseInterestsScreen,
  },
  Home : {
    screen: HomeTab,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas for this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Rather then giving conditional Components to screen prop you can have a container Component to render conditionally according to the parameter you want.

**Example**

```
const InterestsContainer = (props) => {
  return (props.navigation.state.params.interests ? InterestsScreen : ChooseInterestsScreen );
}

export const MainNavigation = StackNavigator({
  Interests: {
    screen: InterestsContainer,
  },
  Home : {
    screen: HomeTab,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Comment: I get the following error here: InterestsContainer(...): A valid React element (or null) must be return. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Comment: Error is pretty clear. You probably have an error while implementing the example. without any code its hard to know where your error.

Answer (score 1):

You should transfer that conditional rendering logic to your `InterestsScreen` component, such that inside its render method, do the check to see if `this.props.navigation.state.params.interests` exists and contains values, and if it doesn't, display a modified version of `ChooseInterestsScreen` as a modal.